# how to trigger email notification or generate error report when ecounter error in processing SSIS interfaces?

Tags: ssis

when using SSIS to processing incoming interface files or generate outgoing interface files from database, may encounter error in certain process task/step.

Can anyone advise how do i capture the error and generate email notification to notify the users or generate error report file to investigate further?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in send mail task to send the email. See [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1731/sending-email-from-sql-server-integration-services-ssis/) for more details.

There is a good solution explaining how to capture the error messages [here](http://agilebi.com/jwelch/2007/05/05/handling-multiple-errors-in-ssis/). You capture the messages in to a variable in the data flow, then pull the messages from that variable in the event handler, then pass them on to the send mail task.

Comment: i tried to follow the advises in this link: how to trigger email notification or generate error report when ecounter error in processing SSIS interfaces?

and there is a guide here: agilebi.com/jwelch/2007/05/05/handling-multiple-errors-in-ssis/ on how to capture error messages.

I tried to follow the steps but i am still not able to get the error messages. Any advises

How can i check in the variable whether the value is passed in correctly?

Comment: You can use the built in debug tools i.e. add a breakpoint and a watch on that variable.